# check if specific entry from table A exists in table B and if yes, ignore those values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named: workers and a table named: schedule with the following format:

workers:

```
id, name
```

schedule:

```
day, month, name
```

I need to interrogate table "workers" to give me 2 random names. But these two names must not be in table "schedule" for a specific day.

This is what I've got so far, but it doesn't work as supposed:

```
    SELECT name FROM workers WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM schedule WHERE month='June' AND day='1' AND name="Johnny") ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2;
```

It returns:

```
Empty set!
```

Thank you!

Comment: select w.name from workers w, schedule s where s.month!='June' and s.day!='1' and w.name=s.name ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2; btw instead of name in the table schedule, it's better usage to use for example id_workers as a foreign key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this could function

```
SELECT name 
FROM workers 
WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM schedule WHERE month='June' AND day='1')
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: Thank you, with some minor modifications to my tables, this will do!